# Error rased in reshape function in R, with count aggregation.

Tags: r

I am working on a simple dataframe looks like:

```
id    event
111    hit
111    eat
222    hit
222    eat
222    eat
333    hit
333    hit
333    hit
333    eat
```

I want to reshape and count based on the event type. So the output table should looks like:

```
id   hit   eat
111  1     1
222  1     2
333  3     1
```

my R command is:

```
dcast(mydf, id ~ event, value.var = "event", fun.aggregate=count)
```

It reports error:

```
Error in dim(ordered) <- ns : 
  dims [product 167260] do not match the length of object [334520]
```

I don't understand where I am wrong. Please help...

Comment: Don't you just need `table(df$id, df$event)` ?

Comment: but the output is not dataframe

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$id, df$event))`

Comment: Your example seems to work perfectly by the way - `dcast(dat, id ~ event, value.var="event", fun.aggregate=length)` - I just subbed out `count` for `length` , which apparently might cause an issue here.